# Combining messages from multiple devices

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

Is there a recommended way in the Azure ecosystem to join the JSON messages sent by two or more separate devices at approximately the same time in order to run them through, for example, an Azure ML webservice.

The goal of this would be running a real time analysis with data coming from multiple devices.

Thank you

Edit : 
Perhaps I should have phrased my question better, but I am currently using Azure Stream Analytics in order to capture the data sent from a device to Azure ML, which works fine (from learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/…). Now I want to do the same thing but with multiple devices that each send part of the information that Azure ML needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Azure Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/) which allows you to work on windows of time.
This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial) shows how to integrate ASA with Machine Learning.
And you can easily set the input of an ASA job to an IoT Hub.

Comment: Perhaps I should have phrased my question better, but I am currently using Azure Stream Analytics in order to capture the data sent from a device to Azure ML, which works fine (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-weather-forecast-machine-learning). Now I want to do the same thing but with multiple devices that each send part of the information that Azure ML needs.

Comment: I will accept your answer as I found the way to work with ASA on windows of time. Thank you.